# Does the app access_token obtained from facebook graph API change?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am referring to the access token one can obtain using the following url.

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APPID&client_secret=APPSECRET&grant_type=client_credentials

Answer (score 2):

If you have not requested offline_access permission, then the access_token will expire. The time before it will expire is returned when you get the access token.

Comment: what you are saying is true for user access token - not for app access token.

Comment: The app access_token is assumed has offline_access permission and does not expire.

Answer (score 0):

If you request offline_access permission then the access_token will not expire. However there is a major change in authentication coming up. As of October 3, 2012, the offline_access permission will be deprecated. So if you are building any new application DO NOT use this permission. Below is the change documentation by Facebook:

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#october-2012

Also more details on the removal of this permission:

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/